# Add items to spinner while open

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-view, android-spinner

It's there any way to add and refresh items in a spinner after a user has clicked on it and the drop down list is displayed?
For example:

1. User clicks spinner, and starts listening for some events.
2. Drop down list is showing.
3. When the listener receives a callback, a new item is added to the drop down list(without closing and reopening the list).

Sorry for not having code, but I've been scouring the web and the APIs and the only things I find about this are for populating the adapter before it's opened. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as SpinnerAdapter doesn't really have a notifyDataSetChange() function, try calling:

```
mSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
```

This will refresh your drop down views, if you find better solution I would love to see it.